# Flux Store and Mongoose Model code sharing

Tags: mongoose, flux

We have Flux stores on the client and mongoose models on server. At the moment our flux stores are a combination of mongoose models schema and UI flags. For example our appointment store data looks like following -

```
 function AppointmentData() {

     this.Data = {
          Appointment : AppointmentMongooseModel,
          Personel : PersonnelMongooseModel
     };

     this.Config = {
        Clinics : ClinicsMongooseModel,
        Services : ServicesMongooseModel,
        SelectedClinics:[],
        SelectedDays : []
     }   
  }
```

Is this the right approach to share code between flux stores and server mongoose model?

Could this cause more problems in the future when the store does not want to use all the properties from the server and vice versa?